# Require key file by path in Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have the functions for Google Cloud Function that needs to require json key file.

For example:

```
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'your_service_account_email@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE = require('./path/to/your/service_account.json');

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    null,
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'],
    null
);
```

How I can get access for SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE? Where should I upload the file and how next do I will find its path?

Answer (score -1):

This is a key from the private/public key pair that you create. It will be wrapped inside a JSON (at least that is the common usage). See examples [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) and documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account). Never share your private key, but you can freely share your public key (in fact it is required that you share your public key). And don't put your private key into a source control (git repo).

You can find a lot of good information about asymmetric asymmetric cryptography (public key cryptography) online.

In case you are wondering where to add the key file, it should be here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-oauth-jwt#creating-a-service-account-using-the-google-developers-console

*UPDATE*:
Where should you add the file to be able to access it:

> One of the best practice is to put the file in a bucket, to allow the function service account (the default one or a specific identity) to read this bucket and to load the file at runtime. One of the main reason is that you don't have to commit your security file, you just have to keep a reference to a bucket.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367558/how-to-use-a-json-config-file-in-a-google-cloud-function)

Comment: Thank you. I know about this key. I don't know where I must store this file for access from google cloud function by path.

Comment: Appended the answer with a link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-oauth-jwt#creating-a-service-account-using-the-google-developers-console

Comment: I see this answer gets downvoted and admittedly I think I was in a rush to answer it. I appended the answer with how to access a json file from another stack overflow post.