# How to use a JSON config file in a google cloud function

Tags: node.js, json, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to set up a google cloud function to use a cloud storage SDK. That cloud storage SDK requires a JSON formated configuration file that it generates when you register your application with your account. I am using Node.js 10

How I import a JSON object into a google cloud function?

So far I've already tried using the environment variables in the google cloud console. I copied the json object into the value space and it did not work. I tried uploading the project as a zip file with a normal json file and used the fs module to read the json object but that did not work.

Here is the JSON object I need to use. (obviously the keys have been changed to random values

```
{
    "randomAppSettings": {
      "clientID": "jk321hgg5h1l5j234gjl23",
      "clientSecret": "akhfusafkhdsjghlsakdfkdj",
      "appAuth": {
        "publicKeyID": "243532kj5kh",
        "privateKey": "23k4j32hvj4hh",
        "passphrase": "jk321g5hg12l534kj521"
      }
    },
    "enterpriseID": "4235614785",
    "webhooks": {
      "primaryKey": "3jh24gkj34`j2hkhj23g1hk5gk2jhkjhk",
      "secondaryKey": "125gk4j5h325432bkjhkjhekjh642"
    }
  }
```

As you can see its not a simple key/value pair, I don't know if that has something to do with it.

This is the method of reading the information used in the actual code (with the normal fs attempt)

```
let configFile = fs.readFileSync("baconConfig.json");
const randAppConfig = JSON.parse(configFile); //variable for security and configuration management
```

The expected results are to read the file with the JSON.parse method, however the log is outputting errors that are centered around trying to read the json config.

Any help please?

Comment: One thought would be to package you JSON file with your Node.js app when it is deployed.  You an then read your JSON into your app using a simple require() ... see https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2908-you-can-use-require-to-load-json-javascript-object-notation-files-in-node-js.htm

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message and stack trace that you get.

Comment: Private keys are better placed in Google Secrets than in an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best practice is to put the file in a bucket, to allow the function service account (the default one or a specific identity) to read this bucket and to load the file at runtime.
One of the main reason is that you don't have to commit your security file, you just have to keep a reference to a bucket.

Answer (score -1):

You can place your JSON strings in environment variables. Maybe you have to remove line breaks.
Usage in Cloud Functions code (Python):

```
import os
import json

foobar_json_string = os.environ.get('foobar_json_string', '{}')
foobar_dict = json.loads(foobar_json_string)
```